# Restrict Speech Recognition to one language only

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

I have one query About Android Speech Recognition.

I want to restrict a speech recognizer to recognize only given/selected language.

For example,  if I select "en" as preferred language, speech recognizer should only return English words after Speech to text conversion. And should ignore other languages words like,

If I say "Hola" or "Bonjour", it should return null or should not recognize the word, or no response, etc

I did try `EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE`, but no success.

Also, all other links are about how to add multiple languages, but I want opposite of it, I want single language to be recognized by the speech recognizer.

If there is any workaround or if there is some specific way to use `EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE`, kindly do share here.

Comment: It is easier to filter language on recognized results.

Comment: @jared I tried to find language recognizer of text as we have in iOS but there is no such library in android except for paid API of Google